# How implement deploy tracking on Next.js without a custom server?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, rollbar

I'm working on a **Next.js** project and we're running it **WITHOUT** the [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server), using the `next build + next start`.

On the backend, when a new version is deployed and starts to run, we send a log to a service warning the team of the success of the deploy, so we want to do the same for the Next.js frontend.

My question is: where can we add this `log` that will only be send when the build is already finished and the new version is running for the first time (with success)?

- Would be nice if this log is only send a single time for each new build;
- Also, this log need to be send only on runtime, and not on build time;
- One more thing that would be nice for the deploy tracking is to send the log only when the frontend successfully load;

With the custom server, is enough for us if we log on the `app.prepare`, but we're really trying to skip the implementation of the custom server.

There's a central point/callback that is only called a single time after the `yarn start`?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create a custom `next.config.js`, and listen for the `phase-production-server` phase.

```js
const { PHASE_PRODUCTION_SERVER } = require('next/constants');

module.exports = (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
  if (phase === PHASE_PRODUCTION_SERVER) {
    // Post to an API
  }

  return defaultConfig;
};
```

It's not perfect but I'm not sure there's a handler for when the server is ready. I'm also curious about that and asked a similar-but-different question in [their discussion section.](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/28424)

You can [read more about phase here.](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/introduction#:%7E:text=phase%20is%20the%20current%20context%20in%20which%20the%20configuration%20is%20loaded.)